# Get bundle product items in cart of Magento

Tags: magento, bundle, shopping-cart, checkout

Pls help me in my trouble. I need to get bundle products from cart of magento, and than I need to get the selected items of every bundle product. How can I do this? Thanx!

Comment: and what you have tried to do to achieve this?

Comment: I can get bundle product and can get all items of bundle product, but get selected items from cart I dont know how.

Comment: @AlexSkiLLer did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 6):

In magento 1.8.1

```
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $_item) :
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
        if($_product->getTypeId()==='bundle') :
            $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
            ?>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($options['bundle_options'] as $option):?>
                    <dt><?php echo $option['label'] ?></dt>
                    <?php foreach ($option['value'] as $sub) :?>
                        <dd><?php echo $sub['qty'] . " x " . $sub['title'] . " " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($sub['price'])  ?></dd>
                <?php endforeach;
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif;

    endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();
     $selectionCollection =$product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
    $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);
   foreach( $options as $option )
    {
        $_selections = $option->getSelections();
        foreach( $_selections as $selection )
        { 
          $product_simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($selection->getId()); 
        }
    }
```

Hope this will work for you. :)
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
if($_product->getTypeId()==='bundle') {
        $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
        ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php
            foreach ($options['bundle_options'] as $option) {?>
                <dt><?php echo $option['label'] ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $option['value'][0]['title'] ?></dd>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </dl>
    <?php }
```

This work for Input Type "Dropdown" for bundle items